# How to tell if a JAXB element <MyRequest/> is "empty"

Tags: java, jaxb

How can I tell programmatically if a JAXB element is "empty" ?

```
<fis:MyRequest/>
```

Normally, with data, it may look like this:

```
<fis:MyRequest>
    <fis:ABC>X</fis:ABC>
    <fis:XYZ>6000</fis:XYZ>
</fis:MyRequest>
```

But sometimes it can be empty and I want to isolate these cases in code.

In this case it is easy to check

```
if (myRequest.getAbc() == null && myRequest.getXyz() == null) { ... }
```

But imagine if there are many more sub-elements, this won't be practical.

I thought about generating the myRequest element to a string, and checking if it was a single tag ending with `/>`but this seems like using an elephant to chase a grasshopper (overkill, in other words).

Is there a handy utility function sitting around some place that does this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: nope. classes were generated from xsd with `maven-jaxb2-plugin` version 0.8.3

Comment: what is your flow? Are you using an XSD

Comment: @GV yes, I'm using an XSD from a vendor and generating java classes with the maven-jaxb2-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the `equals()` method has been generated (see note below) you can compare the JAXB element to a `new` instance of the same element type.

```
MyRequest EMPTY_MYREQYEST = new MyRequest();

if (myRequest.equals(EMPTY_MYREQUEST)) { ... }
```

I can't see any disadvantage to this approach (?)

note: The `-Xequals` and `-XhashCode` flags are most likely required when generating java code from the xsd